# Query Table using value echod on view without submit the from again

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

I need some hepl on who to handle this issue, have two tables categories_meta_data

> meta_category_id | meta_category_name 
>      ------------------|------------------------------------- 
>      395             |  Soft Drinks 
>      11111           |  Hot Drinks

and  item_meta_data

> meta_item_name | meta_category 
>      ----------------|------------------------------- 
>       Pepsi          |  395

On my model i fetch data using

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM `item_meta_data`");
return $query->result();
```

On my controller

```
$data['listitems'] = $this->List_items->listItems();
$this->load->view('header2', $data);
$this->load->view('menu');
$this->load->view('items',$data);
$this->load->view('footer2');
```

on view

```
foreach ($listitems as $row) {
  $item_name = $row->meta_item_name;
  $item_category = $row->meta_item_cartegory;

  echo '<tr class="odd gradeX">';
  echo "<td> {$item_name} </td>"; 
  echo "<td>";
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM `cartegories_meta_data` WHERE `meta_cartegory_id` LIKE '$item_category'";
  $view = $this->db->query($sql);

  foreach ($view as $row) {
  $item_category_name = $row->meta_cartegory_name;
  echo $item_category_name ;

  echo "</td>"; }

  }
```

what am trying to archive is when my user when viewing item list on a form (view) to see

> Item name    |  category   
>   --------------------------- 
>   Pepsi        | Soft Drinks

How can I use the meta_category value from table item to fetch the actual name of the category in table categories_meta_data and show the results ( CodeIgniter Frame Work)

Comment: Learn about JOINs. http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`JOIN` the categories_meta_data e.g.

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT item_meta_data.*, categories_meta_data.* FROM `item_meta_data` JOIN categories_meta_data ON item_meta_data.meta_category=categories_meta_data.meta_category_id");
```

Then in you view change `$item_category` to:

```
$item_category = $row->meta_category_name;
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks! Ross Wilson... It worked... I wonder why I never thought about using JOIN..